# Variable assignment difference

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, variable-assignment, fibonacci

I'm currently on an exercise to produce the position of a given Fibonacci number.

My initial code was :

```
n = int(input())
a = 0
b = 1
new_list = []

for i in range(n+1):
    new_list.append(a)
    a = b 
    b = a + b 

print(new_list)
```

However, The right way to execute the code is :

```
n = int(input())
a = 0
b = 1
new_list = []

for i in range(n+1):
    new_list.append(a)
    a, b = b, a + b

print(max(new_list))
```

What's the difference between a,b = b, a + b and a = b, b += a written in separate lines?

I asked for help from ChatGPT, but I don't quite understand the difference between my code and the corrected code, given that my code returns the wrong answer and ChatGPT is correct.

Comment: When you use 2 lines you first change `a`. Then in the following line `b = a + b` uses the new value for `a` where you wanted the old one.

Comment: The key difference between your initial code and the corrected version lies in the way the variables a and b are updated within the loop. Let's break down both versions to understand this difference better.

Comment: @Matthias ah that makes sense now. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right-hand side is fully evaluated before performing the assignment. In the second second snippet, you'd first add a+b, and then assign `a=b` and b=`a+b`, where the value of `a` is taken **before** it's overridden with `b`.

In the first snippet, `a` is overriden with `b`, and then `b` is assigned `a+b`, which just doubles its value.

If you wanted to separate the assignments for better readability, you could use a temporary variable:

```py
tmp = a + b
a = b
b = tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference between

a=b
b=a+b

and

a,b=b,a+b

is that when you do in the first method the value of 'a' will changed(updated with value 'b') so that in the next line "b=a+b" since the value of 'a' is updated with value 'b' it will be calculated as 'b+b' which is '2b'. But in the second method both 'a' and 'b' will be updated to 'b' and 'a+b' simultaneously. So the values will not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The very important difference i am seeing here is the "print(max(new_list))". Here it is requestng for the max number in the list which will provide you the only number you need.

Comment: My mistake. Both are supposed to be print(max(new_list)) to return the number of a given position.

Comment: Oh Then the overwriting of the variable "b" could be the issue.